# Not able to run commands over SSH (using Zsh)

Tags: ssh, gnome-terminal, xterm, zsh

I recently changed my `.zshrc` to remap interrupt from <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>, and suddenly I'm not able to run any commands on machines that I SSH into. No matter what command I type, it simply ignores it and doesn't output anything. Even `echo hi` returns nothing.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> is the keyboard mapping for Linefeed. When you map <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>, it means that it will interrupt the command any time you push the return key over ssh, which is basically right when you run the command.

Try mapping interrupt to a different hotkey so that it doesn't overlap with another common key combination.